# Count Subrecord w/ NetSuite Custom Field and Forumla

Tags: sql, netsuite

I want to create a custom field that counts subrecords (not sure if I'm using that term properly). For example, I'd like to add a custom field to the Customer entity type that shows a count of messages (emails) associated with that Customer record.

My instinct is to say:

```
COUNT({messages})
```

But, it doesn't appear there is a COUNT() function in NetSuite SQL.

Anyone know how do do something like this?

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but this is doable in NetSuite using summary options. If creating the search in the UI you will see the second column in the Results tab is "Summary". Select "Count" for this value and it will count. I would recommend if you are doing this from the customer records to do Messages : InternalId (or as a formula value - {messages.internalid} ). You want to count by an internal id that is unique if you want to know the total number. If you count by say Messages : Subject, then any messages that share the same subject will be counted together. That doesn't sound like what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

This is an alternate solution as formula may not be able to achieve this:

Add a custom field on customer to store the count.

Write an "after submit" user event script on message

```
if(message.getFieldValue('entity') !== null && message.getFieldValue('entitytype' === 'customer')){
    //Do a saved search for message where entity equals the current entity
    // search result count would point to number of messages for customer
   // nlapiSubmitField() for your custom counter field
}
```